# How does git know its in a git repo

Tags: git

I am interested in how `git` actually knows it is in a git repo. My first inkling is it just climbs up the folder structure to the root (which may involve permission errors). Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's it. You can also tell it explicitly where all the pieces are, with options or environment variables.

The full docs are spelled out kind of piecemeal, you can search `git help git` for "discovery" to find the `--git-dir` option on the `git` command itself and, later on, an exact specification of its normal discovery discussed under the [`GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITDISCOVERYACROSSFILESYSTEMcode) environment variable's docs, which is used to extend that discovery's scope.

Edit: there's two possible conditions: you could start inside a work tree, or you could start inside an actual repository (like the one conventionally kept in a `.git` dir at the top of a work tree). I answered for the "inside a work tree" case, [Schwern answered for the "inside a repository proper" case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499840/1290731), tl;dr: yes, it walks back up the directory nesting, until it finds either a work tree or a repository. A work tree has a `.git` with a repository in it, a repository has `refs` and `objects` and `HEAD` as described in that answer.

Comment: link: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITDISCOVERYACROSSFILESYSTEMcode

Answer (score 6):

The rule of thumb is that Git just looks up the file path to find a .git directory, but that's not really true. [As Edward Thomson asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499497/how-does-git-know-its-in-a-git-repo#comment115801018_65499531), what about [bare repos](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) with no .git directory?

Here's the gory details. It starts in [setup_git_directory_gently_1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/71ca53e8125e36efbda17293c50027d31681a41f/setup.c#L1051) searching for Git directories.

If `GIT_DIR` or `--git-dir` is set it uses that. Else it begins searching from either the current working directory, or the paths given with `-C`.

1. If there is a `.git` *file* with the first line `gitdir: <path>` it will use that path.
2. If `.git/` (a non-bare repository) is a Git directory, it uses that.
3. If `./` (a bare repository) is a Git directory, it uses that.
4. Moves up a directory and starts again *unless*...

   1. It has hit any `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES`.
   2. `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` is not true and it has hit a filesystem boundary.

It is a Git directory if ALL of these are true, from [`is_git_directory`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/setup.c#L339).

1. `HEAD` contains a syntactically valid reference.
2. There's an accessible `objects` directory, or whatever GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY is set to.
3. There's an accessible `refs` directory.

[It is a non-bare Git directory](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/setup.c#L379) if it is a Git directory AND its parent is `.git`.

Here is the minimum to convince Git it has found a "Git directory".

```
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 schwern staff 27 Dec 29 14:50 HEAD
dr-xr-xr-x 2 schwern staff 64 Dec 29 14:50 objects
drwxr-xr-x 2 schwern staff 64 Dec 29 14:50 refs

./objects:
total 0

./refs:
total 0

$ cat HEAD 
ref: refs/heads/yarblockos
```

Accessible `objects` and `refs` directories, and a HEAD file with a syntactically valid reference.

If that is in a `.git` directory then it is a non-bare repository.

Comment: Yarrr, blockos! It's talk like a pirate day in block-land!  Seriously, just wondering: "yarblockos"?

Comment: @torek Appypolly loggies. It's [nadsat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadsat) so you pony it will rabbit with any chepooka reference.

Comment: Aha. Never read that (avoided it and the movie based on the reports of ultraviolence, which is not to my taste), but perhaps I should read it after all.

Answer (score 0):

A Git repo is a directory with a `.git` directory in it. Git can recourse backwards until it encounters that folder, or cannot go back anymore.

Comment: What about bare repos?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Good question. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499840/14660).